# What account does mrtg usually run as and can this be changed?

Tags: linux, centos, mrtg

CentOS 6 / MRTG 2.16.2

I've noticed that mrtg is running as root on one of my servers and that concerns me.  Is this a requirement?  I didn't see it mentioned in the mrtg documentation. Can this be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, under RunAsDaemon:

> If you want mrtg to run under a particular user and group (it is not
>   recomended to run MRTG as root) then you can use the --user=user_name
>   and --group=group_name options on the mrtg commandline.

```
mrtg --user=mrtg_user --group=mrtg_group mrtg.cfg
```

http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/doc/mrtg-reference.en.html